# Where I should use Service , AsyncTask and Broadcast Receiver?

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver

I'm in little bit confusion where in what case I need to use application components like Service, asyncTask and Broadcast Receiver.

Can any one explain what the exact difference between these there and where I need to use these components?

Answer (score 7):

AsyncTask is a friendly way to create a new thread that performs some work asynchronusly.

A Broadcast Receiver is something like an Event Handler for system events. It can run in 
background and perform an action when something happens, like turning the phone off or turning wifi on..

A Service is just an app that works in background (like a daemon) and serves information to an app or just performs tasks.

Sorry for my English, I try to let me understand but it is not my mother tongue

Comment: Don't go around apologizing, we have seen worse.

Comment: Technically Broadcast Receiver won't run in the background. They are like callbacks and invoked by the operating system

Answer (score 5):

I will get straight to where I have applied these three in my projects so far:

1.Service:Something you want to perform in the background without any user interaction.For instance fetching location data continuously or sending some data continuously to your server.You can also use services  to perform  tasks every few time units.For example sending ten minute background updates.

2.AsyncTask:Making a new thread of execution.Best use I have encountered so far is calling a web service..I did the following using an AsyncTask for web service calls
1.Display Progress bar in onPreExecute()
2.Perform my web service calls in doInBackground(Params...)
3.In onPostExecute(Result) update the UI or do some other stuff with the response from the web service.

3.BroadCastRecievers are like global recievers for your app.They can listen for both System events like a phone restart or a custom event within your app.I used them for starting a service when the phone was restarted,which stopped when we switched off the phone.

Answer (score 2):

Let me explain with a usecase, so you understand it better -

1. AsyncTask - Want to get something from the server, or post something to the server? If we do so on the main thread, the user won't be able to interact with the app. So Asynctask is used, and it performs the network activity in a different thread.
2. Service - Want to manage something in the background? Like get the users' location every 10 minutes or 1 hour, or alert the user when he is crossing a particular area based on the location. The Service makes the app run even when the app is not opened (the user might be doing something else, or the phone is locked, the Service still runs in the background).
3. Broadcast Receiver - Assume, you are tracking location and storing locally (when the internet is down). Not when the internet is up, you want to send all of them. So you register with the OS, that you want to listen for that specific event, and you get control.
   Or when you want the server to know that the device is restarted, then we just have to implement it.

Clear?

Answer (score 1):

A service and its local memory-variables are loaded into memory and is always running

A BroadCast receiver is only garanteed to be in memory and running while processing an event.

A Broadcastreceiver can be removed from memory by the operating system if the memory is low.

Answer (score 1):

"Service" is a component which runs in the background, without interacting with the user. Every developer can create new Services in his application. Services support true multitasking for Android, as they can run in their own process.

"AsyncTask" encapsulates the creation of Threads and Handlers. An AsyncTask is started via the execute() method.the execute() method calls the doInBackground() and the onPostExecute() method. 
Mostly main purpose to download something without user interaction.

"Broadcast receiver" is a class which extends BroadcastReceiver and which is registered as a receiver in an Android Application via the AndroidManifest.xml file(or via code).you can register a BroadcastReceiver dynamically via the Context.registerReceiver() method.
The class BroadcastReceiver defines the onReceive() method. Only during this method your BroadcastReceiver object will be valid, afterwards the Android system can recycle the 
BroadcastReceiver.